# Hero Image does not work correctly when zoomed out

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make a clone of the [discord website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMfxp.gif). And I am facing a lot of problem with the images in the hero section. Please take a look at the gifs I have attched. (notice the hero section bg images when zooming out.)

1. [Discord Website Zoom Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txlxW.jpg)
2. [My Attempt](https://i.imgur.com/6ZTJPY0.mp4)

> Notice that in *My Attempt* I toggled on the `left: 50%` css property
> of image. This was a big image so with `left: 50` it came at the
> position as it is in Discord Website.

**Problem->** As you would have noticed the image in the discord website remains in the center and you basically just see more and more of the image as you zoom out. However in my clone, when zoomed it zooms out from the left side. Please take a look at the follwing code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 92vh;
  background-color: #404eed;
}

.image_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hero">
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FjoxNjB.png" alt="img1">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*(In reality the image that you see in *'My Attempt'* is an svg, however here I have added an png (from Imgur). Don't know if this information helps but yes it is an svg.)*

Can someone please help me out with this, I have really tried to solve this, but was unable, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the `img` horizontally with CSS `left` and `translateX` properties when in `absolute` positioning.

The value of `left` and `translateX` can be adjusted so it matches the desired result.

Example:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Hope that it helps!